# Contract Creation Transaction

Tags: metamask

I was trying to send eth through metamask and it ended up sending my ETH to this address called 'Contract Creation' can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xab8565481d5edcd162da315bf194b349451b37efbe10e068c601a8cfa84728ca

Answer (score 1):

You have not sent a basic Ether transaction, you have created a contract which has the address `0x23a06f51699165975b622258612b77cae9a20c4e`.

Assuming that you did not write a function in that contract to allow you to withdraw that Ether, it is sadly now stuck.

Comment: No i did not. Is there anyway for me to get it out? :(

Comment: Unfortunately, as already stated, you can't get it out if you don't have functionality in the contract to get it out.